# A problem regarding $k\circ (f*g)=(k\circ f)*(k\circ g)$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

My Algebraic Topology book states the following:

> Let $k:X\to Y$ be  continuous path. If $f$ and $g$ are two paths in $X$ with $f(1)=g(0)$, then $$k\circ(f*g)=(k\circ f)*(k\circ g)$$

I'm trying to construct an example to understand this concept better, but going wrong somewhere.

Let $f:[0,1]\to(t,3t)$ and $g:[0,1]\to (t,3-3t)$. Clearly $f(1)=g(0)$. Let $k:\Bbb{R^2}\to\Bbb{R^2}$ be defined as $k:(x,y)\to(x^2,y^2)$. Then the mapping of $f$ will be $f':[0,1]\to(t',9t')$, and $g':[0,1]\to(t',9t'-18\sqrt{t'}+9)$. This can easily be verified. Now $f'*g'=(k\circ f)*(k\circ g)$ is $\left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    (t',18t') & \quad \text{for $t'\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$}\\
    (t',18t'-18\sqrt{2t'-1}) & \quad \text{for $t'\in[\frac{1}{2},1]$}
  \end{array} \right.$

Now we shall determine $k\circ(f*g)$. Here $f*g$ is $\left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    (t,6t) & \quad \text{for $t\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$}\\
    (t,6-6t) & \quad \text{for $t\in[\frac{1}{2},1]$}
  \end{array} \right.$

Hence, $k\circ(f*g)$ is $\left\{
  \begin{array}{l l}
    (t',36t') & \quad \text{for $t'\in[0,\frac{1}{2}]$}\\
    (t',36t'-72\sqrt{t'}+36) & \quad \text{for $t'\in[\frac{1}{2},1]$}
  \end{array} \right.$

So I'm getting $$(k\circ f)*(k\circ g)\neq k\circ (f*g)$$

Could someone please help me out? I realise this might entail a lot of seemingly mundane calculations, but I've been stuck on this for some time now, and would greatly appreciate any inputs.

Comment: What do you mean by «the mapping of $f$»?

Comment: By the way, it is *never* a good idea to write things like «$f=3x$» when what you mean is something like «$f:t\in[0,1]\mapsto 3x\in\mathbb R^2$» or something with a sensible amount of detail —unless, that is, you are writing notes for yourself (which is not the case here!) As things stand, I cannot tell what the domain and codomain of the $f$ in your example are meant to be!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez- I shall keep that in mind.

Comment: You can start now by making expicit what the domain and codomain of the functions you talk about in your questions are: as you see, this lack of detail is behind Hagen's answer. By now, we have two answers starting with «I assume you mean...»

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez- I have made the required corrections.

Comment: As you've defined it, $f(1) = (1,3)$ and $g(0) = (0,3)$, so clearly $f(1)\ne g(0)$.

Comment: @oxeimon- $f(1)\neq (1,3)$. $f(1)=3$. similarly, $g(0)=3$.

Comment: @algebraically_speaking, according to your edit, $f(1)=(1,3)$! (Or rather, you wrote «$f:[0,1]\to(t,3t)$» which, a before, is rather unorthodox notation... One can but guess that you meant $f:t\in[0,1]\mapsto(t,3t)\in\mathbb R^2$» or something. I am not being dense for the pleasure of it: as you have probably noticed, using somewhat standard notation goes a loooong way in getting understood)

Comment: Your latest calculation of $f*g$ is incorrect, too - note that $f(1) = (1,3)$ but $f*g(\frac12) = (\frac12, 3)$.

Comment: You appear to have some extremely worrying standards of notation which in my opinion are more fundamental to fix than trying to answer this question. Learn to write a function first by it's domain and codomain, and then how the function is defined on every element in the domain. Saying "$f*g$ is [some expression involving $t$]" is sloppy, as is "$f\colon [0,1]\to (t,3t)$". You should be writing something like "$f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined by $f(t)=(t,3t)$". If you really must use shorthand, write "$f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^2\colon t\mapsto(t,3t)$".

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $k$ is merely continuous, not a continuous path (that would require $X$ to be an interval). In fact your example $k$ is a continuous map $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^2$, not a path. But your $f$ and $g$ fail to be paths in $\mathbb R^2$. You should have something like $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$, $t\mapsto (t,3t)$ and $g\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb R^2$, $t\mapsto (t+1,3-3t)$

---

After your edits, note that $f(t)=(t,3t)$, $g(t)=(t,3-3t)$ and $k(x,y)=(x^2,y^2)$ implies $(k\circ f)(t)=(t^2,9t^2)$, $(k \circ g)(t)=(t^2,9-18t+9t^2)$, hence (of course) $(k\circ f)(1)=(1,9)=(k\circ g)(0)$. No square root gets introduced anywhere.

Comment: Why do $f$ and $g$ fail to be paths? Isn't $y=3x$ a path in $\Bbb{R^2}$?

Comment: Please forgive my notation here. I am banking on the assumption that people will understand my problem even with non-standard notation.

Comment: @algebraically_speaking, «Let $f=3x$» is not even non-standard notation  for describing a map going from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R^2$!

Comment: maybe he means the graph of the function y = 3x (under some parametrization)?

It is pretty bad though. If you want to define a path, you need to describe a rule that assigns to every point of $[0,1]$, a point of the space your path is in.

Comment: The required corrections have been made.

Comment: You write «hence (of course) etc» but it is not true that $(k\circ f)(1)=(k\circ g)(0)$» :-)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I'm assuming that $k : X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous *map*.

In this case, all your identity is saying, is that if you first concatenate your paths (ie, form $f*g$, then use $k$ to send the resulting path to $Y$), it's the same as first sending the paths $f$ and $g$ to $Y$ via $k$ (getting $(k\circ f), (k\circ g))$, and then concatenating the result.

A nice way to think about this is taking $X = \mathbb{R}^3$, $Y = \mathbb{R}^2$, and $k$ to be some projection map. In your head, you should think of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as lying above $\mathbb{R}^2$, and the projection map is basically the ``shadow'' of points/paths in $\mathbb{R}^3$, under some bright light that lies far above you, which shines through $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto $\mathbb{R}^2$.

In this case, drawing the concatenation $f*g$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then looking at the shadow, is clearly the same as drawing each path in $\mathbb{R}^3$ separately, looking at their shadows, and noticing that their shadows are joined head to tail!

Comment: Thanks! But here, I'm mainly looking for where I'm going wrong in my example

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things wrong.  The biggest one is that you are reparameterizing $t'=t^2$.  So in your concatenated path $f*g$, $t$ traces from $0$ to $1/2$ in the first term so $t'$ traces from $0$ to $1/4$.